# How do I write unit test in GCP client api (Golang)?

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform

I have a go program that leverages Google Cloud Platform client API (golang) to automate some of the infrastructure creation. The code works great but I have a trouble of writing unit test.

I couldn't find any example/resource to interchange the implementation of GCP client api with a mock interface like what AWS provide (https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/blob/main/example/service/sqs/mockingClientsForTests/ifaceExample.go)

Is there any documentation of how to write unit test with GCP client API?

Comment: That depends on what GCP services you are using. GCP provides some mocks [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go-testing).

Comment: Yeah...I saw those as well. I need the compute services.

Comment: Because you can easily extend interface in Go, I don't the issue to create your own mock! Or you might want to keep the logic of the library but not to send the API Call at the end, correct?

Comment: I suggest another approach. Do not mock. Run against the real thing, in a parametrized way, so that, for example, you can use smaller/less expensive resources and different endpoints when testing. Conceptually, it is the same approach taken by https://terratest.gruntwork.io/, although it tests Terraform code, it tests the real infra. It might take more time than mocking everything, but it will also give more realistic results.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere yes, I don't want to send API call at the end. I just don't see how gcp api extend the interface.